# check for duplicate values in dataframe in column within two index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, duplicates

I have a dataframe as shown in the excel file

[image]

I want to find the duplicate values according to the id's like `ID 0 and ID 1` the values in **nn_id** columns are `366 393` which are not same so further we check the values of `ID 2 and ID 3`  the values in **nn_id** columns are same `595 595` so if values are same them print the values from columns **nn_id** , **slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X** and **slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y**
So the ouput would be in the form of dictionary `{595:[(492,260),(491,248)]}` Further check the values of `ID 4 and ID 5` which are `458 486` which are not same so do nothing.

I am sorry if its confusing but I want to check the two two ID's **nn_id** values if same then make a dictionary of adjacent column values.

Comment: Do you always want to compare if the value is the same as the value on the next line? Or can it be any duplicates in the table.

Comment: yes in the next line only its like iterating index with step 2

Comment: try using dataframe.groupby('nn_id').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you're after? There might be more elegant ways to achieve the same. I've assumed you have a `DataFrame` `df` with your table.

```
df_shift = df.shift(1)    # shift database with 1 row
same_idx = df['nn_id'] == df_shift['nn_id']

# get column positions for columns of interest
col1_pos = df.columns.get_loc('slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X ')
col2_pos = df.columns.get_loc('slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y')
nn_idx_pos = df.columns.get_loc('nn_id')
my_dict = {}   # define empty dict to store your results.
for i in np.where(same_idx)[0]:   # for each row where the nn_idx value is the same
    # define the value that you're after
    my_value = [(df.iloc[i-1, col1_pos], df.iloc[i-1, col2_pos]),
                (df.iloc[i, col1_pos], df.iloc[i, col2_pos])]
    # and add element to dictionary
    my_dict[df.iloc[i, nn_idx_pos]] = my_value
```